# What little clock means on the green bullet of method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

In autocompletion popup there are green bullets with method names.
[image]
I know that line crossing method's bullet means that the method is deprecated.
But what the little clock means?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means it's a `synchronized member`.

[Source](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm?resultof=%22icon%22%20)

Comment: Thanks! I kept thinking it meant that it's deprecated.